# Hide and show columns using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show and hide columns and my code isn't doing it's job.

Basically I want to be able to hide and show columns based on the class name.

My functions to hide and show the columns are not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    appendHeader();
    select();
    var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());
    appendBody(amountOfDayEnds);
});

$('#group').change(function () {
   select();
});

//Change Header based on the select
function select() {
    var group = $('#group').val();
    // Get the column API object
    console.log(group);
    switch (group) {
        case "DDA":
            hideColumn("mtg");
            hideColumn("sav");
            showColumn("dda");
            break;
        case "SAV":
            hideColumn("mtg");
            showColumn("sav");
            hideColumn("dda");
            break;
        case "MTG":
            showColumn("mtg");
            hideColumn("sav");
            hideColumn("dda");
            break;
    }
}

function hideColumn(className){

    var columnIndex = $("#dataTable thead tr th."+className).index();

    $("#dataTable thead tr th:eq("+columnIndex+")").hide();

    $("#dataTable tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+columnIndex+")").hide();
    });
}

function showColumn(className){

    var columnIndex = $("#dataTable thead tr th."+className).index();

    $("#dataTable thead tr th:eq("+columnIndex+")").show();

    $("#dataTable tbody tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td:eq("+columnIndex+")").show();
    });
}


//Append Header
function appendHeader() {
    var thead = '<thead>';
    thead += "<tr class='text-primary text-center'>";
    thead += '<th>Day</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 400</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4044</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4045</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 300</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 310</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 700</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 710</th>';
    thead += '</tr>';
    thead += '</thead>';

    $('#dataTableHead').append(thead);
}
```

**EDIT: it seems like I'm hidding only one column of each type. I want to hide all columns with class name.**

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: when you call your functions?

Comment: We can't really help without a live example..

Comment: @ColinCline ... hideColumn("mtg"); and showColumn("mtg")

Comment: no, the `select()` function was that one i meant.

Comment: it seems like I'm hidding only one column of each type. I want to hide all columns with class name. **I will edit my select**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be more simpler than that. You adding an element into the DOM by js so its better to cache it by `$(document).find()` so in this case you are always sure js will find it and never will get element doesn't exist error. You use a switch case that is not recommend in your situation (better if/else)

**Note**: there is some function that will manipulate/add some element to this table that you missed to add in your code for us so this code works fine with your current code. if its not work for `td`, because you didnt add them in your code and i dont know how is look like or what classes they have.
[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/2rwnfeek/)

**Js/jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    appendHeader();
    select();
    var amountOfDayEnds = parseInt($('#amountOfDayEnds').val());
    appendBody(amountOfDayEnds);
});

$('#group').change(function () {
   select();
});

//Change Header based on the select
function select() {
    var group = $('#group').val();
    // Get the column API object
    console.log(group);
    if(group == 'dda'){
            hideColumn("mtg");
            hideColumn("sav");
            showColumn("dda");
    } else if(group == 'sav'){
            hideColumn("mtg");
            showColumn("sav");
            hideColumn("dda");

    } else {
            showColumn("mtg");
            hideColumn("sav");
            hideColumn("dda");

    }
}

function hideColumn(className){
    $(document).find("#dataTableHead thead th."+className).hide();
}

function showColumn(className){
    $(document).find("#dataTableHead thead th."+className).show();

}


//Append Header
function appendHeader() {
    var thead = '<thead>';
    thead += "<tr class='text-primary text-center'>";
    thead += '<th>Day</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 400</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4044</th>';
    thead += '<th class="dda">Type 4045</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 300</th>';
    thead += '<th class="sav">Type 310</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 700</th>';
    thead += '<th class="mtg">Type 710</th>';
    thead += '</tr>';
    thead += '</thead>';

    $('#dataTableHead').append(thead);
}
```

Comment: people are ready for downvote. I am still editing my answer and some one gave me down vote. stackoverflow is marathon? almost write code in 40 sec so ofc i missed something

Comment: @GeaperonPC You didnt include td in your code look at your code. you almost missed this function `appendBody(amountOfDayEnds);`

Comment: Now only the headers are wrong http://prntscr.com/hl6hub . They are all to the left

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the OP problem, You must update it, and @GeaperonPC you don't have to accept an answer that doesn't solve the OP problem since that will affect the future readers .. (If the problem was solved of chat the _OP/answers_ should be adjusted)

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki to be honest its works based on what OP provide for me. check jsfiddle. If OP copy/paste some missed function that i asked for i'll improve my answer AND for the record i added a **please note** at very begging i publish this post for every readers.